# Ionic - Checking for "" in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I am quite new to Ionic and Typescript and have received a defect of an application where a shell of an order is appearing but the data is all blank.
My code:

```
// Loop over MONITORS
this.monitorArrayLength = this.detail.orderDetailList[i].monitors.length;
for (let j = 0; j < this.monitorArrayLength; j++) {
  this.monitorArray[j] = this.detail.orderDetailList[i].monitors[j];

  if (
    this.monitorArray[j].serialNum !== null ||
    this.monitorArray[j].serialNum !== "" ||
    this.monitorArray[j].status !== null ||
    this.monitorArray[j].status !== "" ||
    this.monitorArray[j].brandModel !== null ||
    this.monitorArray[j].brandModel !== "" ||
    this.monitorArray[j].docId !== null ||
    this.monitorArray[j].docId !== ""
  ) {
    this.showMonitorArray[j] = true; // Show monitor

    if (this.monitorArray[j].docId !== null) {
      this.pdfIconArray[j] = true; // Show pdf icon
    } else {
      this.pdfIconArray[j] = false; // Show normal icon
    }
  } else {
    this.showMonitorArray[j] = false; // Don't show monitor
  }
}
```

So, basically nothing should appear if the results brought back from the database are null or "".

Here is the results I get back from the database:

```
monitors: [{ serialNum: "", status: "", brandModel: "", docId: null }]
```

The code that I have above is not checking correctly for the "" and the shell of the data is still displaying when it shouldn't be.

Is this the right syntax to check for ""?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Ionic or TypeScript. You should change your `if` condition to say

> serialNum is defined AND status is defined AND brandModel is defined AND docId is defined

where "defined" means not `null` or `""`.

```
if (
  (this.monitorArray[j].serialNum !== null &&
    this.monitorArray[j].serialNum !== "") &&
  (this.monitorArray[j].status !== null &&
    this.monitorArray[j].status !== "") &&
  (this.monitorArray[j].brandModel !== null &&
    this.monitorArray[j].brandModel !== "") &&
  (this.monitorArray[j].docId !== null && this.monitorArray[j].docId !== "")
) {
  //...
}
```

But it looks really messy. You could shorten it to a function

```
function isDefined(monitor) {
  const { serialNum, status, brandModel, docId } = monitor;
  return serialNum && status && brandModel && docId;
}
```

which makes sure all these values are not [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: The first way does not work and the monitor shell is still showing with blank data. I have added the function to my code but what would be the syntax of my if statement after I have the function?

Comment: @TheAlmac2 Didn't edit the if condition correctly. I've changed it now. Also, second way: `if (isDefined(this.monitorArray[j]))`.